# Elasticsearch get document count for all fields of index type

Tags: elasticsearch

I would like to get an aggregation with document count on all fields of an index. is this possible or do I have to define every field within a missing to get something similar

Comment: Questions asking us to code sample are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: I could not find anything within the documentation describing how to solve this. Therefore I asked the only solution would be using a missing aggregation but then I will need to specify every field which is actually against what I really want to do this is why I have no code to solve as the issue is not yet solved.